# Triggering multiple individual JavaScript functions via URL without a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, hash

I'm building a simple webapp using NFC(near field communication), which involved certain tags being programmed with the URL of my website + a hash that will trigger a specific JavaScript function.

For example, "www.website.com/index.html#hide/one" will hide the element labeled "one" on the webpage. Simple enough, right? I thought it would be.

I've since learned that when you tap an NFC tag, it opens the URL in a new webpage/tab. I think this could be averted if my webpage checked to see if there are any other open pages and closes them, though.

If there's a better way to do this(trigger JavaScript functions on a webpage via a URL to that webpage), please let me know. It's important to note that there are 8 tags(elements) in total, and they all have to be triggered for the game/app to end, which requires it all to be done on the same page, preferably without refreshes(although I could probably rig something up using localstorage so it could be refreshed).

Thanks in advance, I'm just not sure how I would proceed here.

-Mitchyl

EDIT - I should mention that I already am using backbone.js for my routing needs. It's perfect for my situation at the moment,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a hash tag routing libary. http://projects.jga.me/routie/

This will run when your app page loads and read the hash, diverting the logic of your code to do something based on the hash tag, thus you make your items remove on the page in your code logic. No need for lots of pages.

**But!**

If the url launcher on the device launches new windows each time an item is detected, that is a problem since you can't close those windows, other than from the window itself.

**Solution**

The app has a main window for the game, each item is stored in local storage, You can use the local storage event system to detect if another page changes an item, and update the UI in real-time.

```
   addEvent(window, 'storage', function (event) {
       if (event.key == 'item1') {
          item1.innerHTML = event.newValue;
   }
   });
```

When NFC launches a new window, display user feedback that states they have completed a task of the game then close it using a timeout.

Below that window will be the main page window with the update displayed.

Done properly it will work brilliantly. You can also add a nice x close button on the pop windows as tasks are completed.

Comment: That sounds like a great solution. Is it at all possible to send a request from one webpage to another using JavaScript or something similar? I was thinking that if the NFC reached some other page("www.website.com/ex/one"), it might be able to send a request to the main page which would trigger the JavaScript function. But that might not make sense. In which case, I'll just use the awesome solution that you suggested :)

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned in my main post. I already am using backbone.js to manage my routes. It's perfect for my needs at the moment.

Comment: Yes. localstorage has an event system, if a page on the same domain changes a key it fires an event on the other window. I have updated my answer. That gives you a window msg event system. http://html5demos.com/storage-events

Comment: I think this solution will work very well. If its a game where the user scan items, or find points via NFC, it will work fine. Also using localstorage will give the game back-up and improve the options for your game play.

Comment: That's a really awesome demo, actually. This seems like the best solution. Thanks for your awesome answers!

Comment: And yeah, this solution is awesome. I think this is also the best one in terms of mobile-compatibility(unless I'm mistaken). Because who carries around computers with NFC readers, right?

EDIT - Will I still need to use Routie? Or should backbone.js cover this well enough?

Comment: After looking through Routie, I'm not quite sure how I could use Routie to do all this. Do you have experience with it yourself?